# Apache beam CustomTimestamp windowing not firing aggregate functions

Tags: java, apache-beam

I'm reading from Kafka topic and applying customtimestamp from the datetime that I receive from the message in kafka, the example Pojo of the message:

```
class Order implements Serializable {

String orderId;
String amount;

Instant processDate;
```

}

The processDate from the above pojo is used to set the timestamp of kafka records and used for windowing instead of the default event time.

Here is the pipeline code

```
PCollection<@UnknownKeyFor @NonNull @Initialized KV<String, String>> comparator1 = 
            pipeline.apply("Read from source kafka topic", KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                            .withBootstrapServers(pipelineOptions.getSourceKafkaBroker())
                            .withTopic(pipelineOptions.getSourceKafkaTopic())
                            .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                            .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                            .withReadCommitted()
                            .withTimestampPolicyFactory((tp, watermark) -> new CustomTimestampPolicy(watermark, "source watermark"))
                            .withoutMetadata())
                    .apply(Window.<KV<String, String>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(pipelineOptions.getWindowDuration())))
                                    .withTimestampCombiner(TimestampCombiner.EARLIEST))
                    .apply(Values.create())
                    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
                        @ProcessElement
                        public void print(ProcessContext c, BoundedWindow window, PaneInfo pane){
                            long waterMarkmillis = c.timestamp().getMillis();
                            String order = c.element();

                            System.out.println("values from "+identifier +" : "+ order
                                    +" | window "+window

                                    +" | watermark at element "+waterMarkmillis);
                            c.output(order);
                        }
                    }))
                    .apply("Count elements per window ", Count.perElement())
                    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String,Long>, String>() {
                        @ProcessElement
                        public void print(ProcessContext c, BoundedWindow window, PaneInfo pane){
                            long waterMarkmillis = c.timestamp().getMillis();
                            String order = c.element().getKey();
                            Long count = c.element().getValue();
                            System.out.println("values from "+identifier +" : "+ order
                                    +" | window "+window
                                    +" | count "+count
                                    +" | watermark at element "+waterMarkmillis);
                            c.output(order);
                        }
                    }));
```

When the above pipeline is executed everything before "Count elements per window" stage works fine, but even when the new element has timestamp outside of the current window the count step is never executed.

Custom Timestamppolicy

```
public static class CustomTimestampPolicy extends TimestampPolicy<String, String>{

        protected Instant currentWatermark;
        private String identifier;

        public CustomTimestampPolicy(Optional<Instant> currentWatermark, String identifier) {
            this.currentWatermark = currentWatermark.orElse(BoundedWindow.TIMESTAMP_MIN_VALUE);
            this.identifier = identifier;
        }

        @Override
        public Instant getTimestampForRecord(PartitionContext ctx, KafkaRecord<String, String> record) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                Order order = objectMapper.readValue(record.getKV().getValue(), Order.class);
                System.out.println("process date : "+order.processDate);
                Instant currentProcessTimeStamp = Instant.parse(order.getProcessDate());
//                if (currentProcessTimeStamp.isAfter(currentWatermark.getMillis()))
                currentWatermark = new Instant(currentProcessTimeStamp.getMillis());
//                System.out.println(identifier+" current water mark : "+currentWatermark);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
//                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return currentWatermark;
        }

        @Override
        public Instant getWatermark(PartitionContext ctx) {
            return currentWatermark;
        }
    }
```

Example i/p data from kafka:

{
"orderId": "1",
"mid": 111,
"amount": "100",
"processDate": "2023-08-18T06:00:07Z"
}

{
"orderId": "2",
"mid": 111,
"amount": "500",
"processDate": "2023-08-18T06:01:07Z"
}

{
"orderId": "3",
"mid": 111,
"amount": "500",
"processDate": "2023-08-18T06:02:07Z"
}

When using event date, instead of processDate from Order, everything works as expected.
Based on the testing o/p I have a feeling that watermark is not being updated properly, is there a way to know the watermark value? The one that I'm printing in the code doesn't look like watermark but the record custom timestamp value (which is essentially processDate)